# Excel VBA Exclude column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a planning scheme in excel with VBA. In the sheet I have all the days. I look for a code and color the cell. But I would like to exclude the weekends coded with 'z' in the file. 
I have this now:

```
  Dim CurCell As Object
  For Each CurCell In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A7:G41, J7:NI41")

        If UCase(CurCell.Value) = "V" Then
            CurCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)         ' V
 End If   

  Next
```

But this works on all the cells. 
I would like to do something like:

```
if Not CurCell.Rows(7) = Z Then
```

And then check for V. So that if CurCell is at row i and column j, I check if column j at row 7 contains a z.   But I don't know how to do this. 
I could exclude all the columns but that are 52 columns..

Comment: All you're doing is coloring cells? You could do this with conditional formatting  `=AND(A$7<>"Z",A7="V")`  Why does this have to be VBA?

Comment: Several people use it and formatting is then also copied. With Vba it might be a bit more fool proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
If Not Cell(7, CurCell.Column).Value = "Z" Then
  'Your code
End If
```

This statement should check the cell in the row 7 and the column of CurCell is not Z

Comment: this will only look in row 7, not every 7th row, like row 14, 21, so you need to add a loop to it....

Comment: @ShaiRado I don't think OP wants to look in every 7th row, only needs to look at row 7.

Comment: @tigeravatar in that case, I went too far with my code below :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to exclude all rows that are weekends, and have "Z", so basically you are looking to find every 7th row. You could use something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestEverySevenRow()

Dim CurCell As Range

For Each CurCell In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A7:G41, J7:NI41")

    ' current row is divided by 7, therefore it's a weekend
    If CurCell.Row Mod 7 = 0 Then

        ' for debug purpose only
        CurCell.Value = "Current Row divided by 7"

        ' the rest of your code goes here

    End If

Next

End Sub
```